# FastAPI {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}

Tags: python, scikit-learn, fastapi

I am using FAST API for my ML Model.

I have a pipeline.

```py
lr_tfidf = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf),
                     ('clf', LogisticRegression(penalty='l2'))])
```

Now In Fast API, when I want to predict, and display result as API, my code is

```py
app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/predict')
def predict_species(data: str):
    data = np.array([data])

    prob = lr_tfidf.predict_proba(data).max()
    pred = lr_tfidf.predict(data)
    return {'Probability': f'{prob}', 
            'Predictions':f'{pred}'}
```

I copied it from a tutorial. When I test it on GUI by FASTAPI, it works good as shown in Image, i.e it shows probability and predictions.

[image]

When I go to request URL, as provided by the GUI, which is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict?data=hello` (test data is hello) It gives me error.

```py
{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

On my Terminal, the error message is

```py
INFO:     127.0.0.1:42568 - "GET /predict?data=hello HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: When you call the URL from your browser, the HTTP Method is `GET`. But your endpoint defines it must be `POST`.

Comment: So, I should change it to `GET`? I do not have much experience with APIs, and I was following a blog by someone.

Comment: It depends :) It would work, but it will most probably violate the rules how name endpoints and when to use which method. A good starting point: https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/ But maybe you are designing a RPC (remote procedure call)? Than it can be different as well.

Comment: Thanks, It is working. You can write the answer, I will tick it

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804). as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71568250/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414202/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The method of the endpoint is defined as `POST` (`@app.post('/predict')`). When you call the URL from your browser, the HTTP Method is `GET`.

A simply solution is to change the endpoints method to `GET` via `@app.get`.

But this will most likely violates how REST-API endpoints should be named and when to use what HTTP method. A good starting point is https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/.

Or maybe you are implementing an RPC (remote procedure call)? Than it can be different as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Using curl**

Open a terminal or command prompt and run the following command:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict?data=hello
```

This command uses curl to make a POST request to the specified URL.

**Using Python requests library**

If you prefer using a Python script, first ensure you have the requests library installed. If not, you can install it using pip:

```
pip install requests
```

Then, you can use the following Python script to make the POST request:

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict"
params = {"data": "hello"}

response = requests.post(url, params=params)

print(response.text)
```

This script sends a POST request to the URL with the specified query parameters.

You can also use Postman, or create an api using JavaScript to perform a POST request