# How can I make upload and stream work for audio on fastapi in a single request?

Tags: python-3.x, post, get, fastapi

I am creating an endpoint in `fastapi`. The endpoint has to accept an audio file and stream back another audio file.

Sample code for that:

```
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

def iterfile(stream_file):
    with open(stream_file, mode='rb') as file_like:
        yield from file_like

@app.post("/")
def stream_audio(audio_file: UploadFile):
    <relevant code>
    return StreamingResponse(iterfile('output.wav'), media_type='audio/wav')
```

However If I use the `POST` request, I can not stream content. On the other hand if I use `GET` request, I can not upload file. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) answer your question? Also, have you tried using a `RedirectResponse` from a POST to a GET route, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804)?

Comment: @Chris `RedirectResponse` is throwing me `405 Method Not Allowed`.  If I use headers in either `FileResponse` or `StreamingResponse`, it is giving me a download link. I do not see streaming audio the way I can see and stream in a normal `GET` request.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414202/17865804), regarding `405 Method Not Allowed`. As for the "Download" link, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608593/17865804) (if you are using Swagger UI autodocs).

Comment: I have used `RedirectResponse` with `inline` `Content-Disposition` and `GET` and `POST` to solve `405 Method Not Allowed`. But as soon as I add upload file parameter, I get another `422 Unprocessable Entity`. Do you think I am missing something?