# FastAPI returns "405 Method Not Allowed" error when sending an HTTP request

Tags: python, fastapi, http-status-code-405

I have a simple FastAPI endpoint, where I want to receive a string value. In this case, I tried it with a JSON body, but basically it doesn't need to be JSON. I really need only a simple string to separate the requests from each other. Unfortunately, I can't access any of the request parameters with a `GET` method. I also tried `POST` method instead, but I get an error:

request:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/ping/"

payload=json.dumps({"key":"test"})
headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload)

print(response.text)
```

api:

```
@app.get("/ping/{key}")
async def get_trigger(key: Request):

    key = key.json()
    test = json.loads(key)
    print(test)
    test2 = await key.json()
    print(key)
    print(test2)


    return
```

I can't print anything with `post` or `put`:

```
@app.post("/ping/{key}")
async def get_trigger(key: Request):
...
   or

@app.put("/ping/{key}")
async def get_trigger(key: Request):
```

I get a `405 Method not allowed` error.

How can I get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) status code indicates that *"the server knows the request method, but the target resource **doesn't support this method**"*. You get this error **when you attempt, for instance, to send a `POST` request to a `GET` route** (as shown in your first example).

This, however, is not the only issue with your code (on both client and server sides). Below is given an example on how to achieve what you described in the question using [`Path` parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/). The same could be achieved using [`Query` parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/), as well as [`Request Body`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/). Please have a look at [Python requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) on how to specify the parameters/body for each case. I would also highly suggest to take the [FastAPI tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/) online—you'll find most of the answers you are looking for there.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/ping/{ping_id}")
async def get_trigger(ping_id: str):
    return {"ping_id": ping_id}
```

**test.py**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ping/test1'
resp = requests.get(url=url) 
print(resp.json())
```

Related answers to [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) errors can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414202/17865804).

Comment: I get a `404 not found ` with your solution

Comment: Yes, I tried it in the browser. this is the fastapi terminal output: `INFO:     127.0.0.1:64153 - "GET /ping/test1 HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found`. I'm on port 5000 btw

Comment: I know that. If I would use the wrong port I'd not see fastapi printing the INFO. I copy/pasted your code, but by starting the server with  `uvicorn main:app --reload`as described in the doc's I get `ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".`. my file is named main.py

Comment: Btw, I need to read / print `ping_id`on the backend side, not on the client side. The print statement in your solution is on the client side.