# FastAPI and JWTDown - 405 method not allow

Tags: reactjs, jwt, backend, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI as a backend and Vite+React as a Frontend.
As an auth I'm using JWTDown

I've made protected routes on the front end so only logged in users can see the full content of the website.
They're logging in, and successfully getting the token and browser through the website.
Everything works fine until the user refreshes the page, he still gets the token but all the protection won't load and the user gets method not allowed 405.
I'm using the jwt-down from galvanize
https://jwtdown-fastapi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

In the frontend I'm sending this request to get the token:

```
try {
      const loginUrl = `${viteUrl}/token/`;
      const fetchConfig = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        credentials: "include",
      };

      const response = await fetch(loginUrl, fetchConfig);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUserid(data.user.userid);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return null;
    }
  };
```

This is the route on fastapi:

```
@router.get("/token/", response_model=UserToken | None)
async def get_token(
    request: Request,
    user: dict = Depends(authenticator.try_get_current_account_data),
) -> UserToken | None:
    if not user or authenticator.cookie_name not in request.cookies:
        return None  # User not authenticated or cookie not found
    return {
        "access_token": request.cookies[authenticator.cookie_name],
        "type": "Bearer",
        "user": user,
    }
```

I tried the solutions that were suggested here, but it didn't work for me.
[Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75711757/fastapi-get-endpoint-returns-405-method-not-allowed-response)

Comment: Why are doing form with a get?

Comment: using the jwtdown from galvanize and wrote the function according to their docs: https://jwtdown-fastapi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Comment: Are you sure that's the endpoint that giving you the 405 error? What's the actual request that you're sending that's giving a 405? (from the browser's debug network tools)

Comment: @MatsLindh, "@galvanize-inc_jwtdown-for-react.js?" send the GET request to /token
That how I check if the user is authorized or not.
`Request URL:
http://localhost:8000/token
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
405 Method Not Allowe`

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71568250/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804)